# ArrayList in Struts 1 ActionForm is not being populated

Tags: java, html, struts

I have an `ActionForm` (RevisionActionForm) that I am populating from DB2 and displaying on a page. This form has various fields and a class that contains several other classes and `ArrayList`s. The page loads fine and everything displays as I would expect, however when the page is submitted the form no longer has the `ArrayList` elements (all other fields are loaded as expected). I am assuming that the problem stems from the fact that the `ArrayList` is built, but no elements exist for the values to be stored in. The following are relevant code segments (I have omitted what I feel is irrelevant in order to reduce this post).

JSP

```
<logic:notEmpty name="revisionBean" property="revisionData.reasonsData">
    <div>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-size: 15px">
        <strong> 604 Information </strong>
    </div>
    <logic:iterate id="reqReas" name="revisionBean" property="revisionData.reasonsData" indexId="reqReasIdx">
        <div>
            <ao:text name="reqReas" property="reasonCodeId" indexed="true" 
                     label="Reason Code ID ${reqReasIdx+1}: " 
                     size="5" maxlength="5" disabled="true"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ao:text name="reqReas" property="priorityOrNum" indexed="true"
                     label="Priority Or Num ${reqReasIdx+1}: "
                     size="2" maxlength="2" disabled="true"/>
        </div>
    </logic:iterate>
</logic:notEmpty>
```

ActionForm

```
public class RevisionActionForm extends BaseActionForm{

    /**
     * Transfer object for the Revision information.
     */
    private RevisionTO revisionData = new RevisionTO();

    public RevisionActionForm() {   
    }

    public RevisionTO getRevisionData(){
        return revisionData;
    }

    public void setRevisionData(RevisionTO revisionData){
        this.revisionData = revisionData;
    }   
}
```

RevisionTO (Holds ArrayList)

```
public class RevisionTO implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<RevisionReasonsTO> reasonsData = new ArrayList<RevisionReasonsTO>();

    public RevisionTO() {   
    }

    public ArrayList<RevisionReasonsTO> getReasonsData() {
        return reasonsData;
    }

    public RevisionReasonsTO getReasonData(int index) {
        if (reasonsData == null) {
            reasonsData = new ArrayList<RevisionReasonsTO>();
        }
        while (index >= reasonsData.size()) {
            reasonsData.add(new RevisionReasonsTO());
        }
        return reasonsData.get(index);
    }

    public void setReasonsData(ArrayList<RevisionReasonsTO> reasonsData) {
        this.reasonsData = reasonsData;
    }   
}
```

Action
    public class RevisionAction extends Action{

```
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                                 HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

        ActionForward forward = new ActionForward();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        RevisionActionForm revisionForm = (RevisionActionForm) form;
}
```

I have been researching on the net and experimenting for the last week without success. I apologize if this is obvious but I am a bit rusty at Java and new to Struts. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `getReasonData(int index)` and `setReasonsData(ArrayList<RevisionReasonsTO> reasonsData)` to `getReqReas(....)` and `setReqReas`